# AS3: How can you get an Array name from string

Tags: arrays, string, actionscript-3, dynamic, multidimensional-array

I am trying to copy a 2D array in a temporary array to a permanent one. The problem is that the array it's trying to copy to is dynamic.

I was looking for a way to get string (the new arrays name) to act as the arrays actual name, not the value of any part of the array. I have looked around and this is roughly what I came to:

```
(this["dynamicArrayName"]) = tempArray;
```

or

```
(this[variableWithName]) = tempArray;
```

(not even sure thats the best way to copy a 2D array).

However, this doesn't work :(. It comes up with so many errors (not syntax).
If there is some way to turn string into an Arrays/Variables name, it would be fantastic to know about.

Comment: Q1) Are you trying to do this inside a class? Q2) If you are, is this class dynamic, or extending MovieClip?

Comment: It is not inside a class. Should it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just drop the parens in your first example.

```
function someFunc():void {
    var temp:Array = [1,2,3];
    this['someArr'] = temp;
}

trace(this['someArr']);
// will output "undefined"

someFunc();
trace(this['someArr']);
// will output "1,2,3"
```

Comment: hmmm... still doesn't work. When I then try and trace it, it comes out with undefined. Am I allowed to do this inside a function? (Read somewhere it doesn't like that).

Comment: Yeah, sure. You might want to share some more code to make it possible to see what's causing this. Meanwhile you can try this on a new file and see the output.

Comment: !! Thank you very much! I worked it out, ended up not needing to use the temp array, and hang on to an array I passed through the function at the start. This better solution doesn't need to call the array from a string name.

Thank you for putting up with me! (First post).